# Django - form field does not pass validation

Tags: django, django-forms

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u"Локация", default=u'')
    country = models.ForeignKey("Country")

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u"Страна")

class Photo(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, verbose_name=u'Фото')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Location
    fields = ['name', 'country']


photos = MultiFileField(min_num=1, max_num=10)

def save(self, commit=True):
    instance = super(LocationForm, self).save(commit)
    for each in self.cleaned_data['photos']:
        Photo.objects.create(photo=each, location=instance)

    return instance
```

views.py

```
class AddLocationPageView(CreateView):
    model = Location
    form_class = LocationForm
    template_name = 'add_location.html'

class BrowseLocationsPageView(ListView):
    model = Country
    context_object_name = 'countries'
    template_name = "browse_locations.html"
```

add_location.html

```
<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

browse_locations.html

```
{% for country in countries %}
            {{ country }}
{% endfor %}
```

While creating Location object the form field says: "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."

Of course, I do not have any choices, because the design is - if Country is absent in DB, it has to be created during Location creating, and in opposite case (Country is in DB, because someone created it before when he was creating Location) it has to be joined to Location.

Comment: So. What's your question, exactly? [ask]

Comment: If you want the form to be valid with a blank choice field, you need to add `blank=True` to your Country foreign key

Comment: my question - how should I realize such design --> if Country is absent in DB, it has to be created during Location creating, and in opposite case (Country is in DB, because someone created it before when he was creating Location) it has to be joined to Location.